# obj.ttl in Varnish 4.0

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

Question about obj.ttl in Varnish 4.0

I have a small varnish problem and hope anyone can help me.
I am using varnish 4.0 and I want to increase the obj.ttl based on the obj.hits

```
sub vcl_hit {
  if (obj.hits == 1000) {
    set obj.ttl = 7d;
  }
}

sub vcl_fetch {
  set beresp.ttl = 20m;
}
```

Unfortunately, I receive an error.
 Message from VCC-compiler:

```
 Variable 'obj.ttl' is read only.
 At: ('input' Line 46 Pos 21)
```

Answer (score 8):

In Varnish 4, [the entire `obj` variable is read-only](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/whats-new/upgrading.html#obj-is-now-read-only):

> **obj is now read-only**
>
> obj is now read-only. obj.hits, if enabled in VCL, now counts per objecthead, not per object. obj.last_use has been retired.

Use `beresp.ttl` instead ([see the VCL reference](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/reference/vcl.html#beresp)). I suggest reading the entire [Upgrading To Varnish 4](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/whats-new/upgrading.html) document.